# Datagram socket not receiving smpp packets

Tags: java, sockets, packet, datagram, smpp

I'm running Kannel and Smppsim on a virtual machine and sending SMPP packets through them. I see the packets on Wireshark, but when I try to capture them with a datagram packet in java I receive nothing.

Here's my code:

```
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(2775);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buf, 1024);
ds.receive(dp);
String str = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
System.out.println(str);
ds.close();
```

I was doubtful about the port number so I also tried port 60720.

and here's an example of the packet I'm receiving on Wireshark:

[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. and I'm not even sure that is the right way to capture smpp packets. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you saying that `receive` blocks waiting for a packet?

Comment: I don't know which part of my code doesn't let me receive packets.